# ReactJS: Material ui breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries, material-ui, breakpoints

What is the difference between `breakpoints.up`, `breakpoints.down`,  `breakpoints.between` and `breakpoints.value` ?
And what is meant by this code, how breakpoints value is working here? Is `theme.spacing.unit*2*2 = theme.spacing.unit*4`  or it has some other meaning?

```
[theme.breakpoints.up(600 + theme.spacing.unit * 2 * 2)]: {
  width: 600,
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  marginRight: 'auto',
},
```

Comment: There is no special meaning to `[theme.breakpoints.up(600 + theme.spacing.unit * 2 * 2)]`

Comment: Its the same as `theme.spacing.unit * 4`.  I just posted an answer with an explanation of the various breakpoint methods you mentioned. Let me know if it answers your questions.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Material uses the following set of breakpoints. You can customize the *values* of this breakpoint in the theme.

[Breakpoint documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/)

> A breakpoint is the range of predetermined screen sizes that have specific layout requirements.
>
> - **xs** (extra-small): 0px or larger
> - **sm** (small): 600px or larger
> - **md**  (medium): 960px or larger
> - **lg**  (large): 1280px or larger
> - **xl**  (extra-large): 1920px or larger

The functions you asked about (`up`, `down`, `between`) are helpers for creating media queries using the breakpoints defined in the theme.

Note: `breakpoints.up()` and `breakpoints.down()` also accept a number, which will be converted to pixels. This is not true of the other methods.

#### breakpoints.up(breakpoint | number)

Creates a **min-width** media query that targets screen sizes greater than or equal to the given breakpoint.

```js
// Styles will be applies to screen sizes from "sm" and up
[theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
  // styles
}
```

#### breakpoints.down(breakpoint | number)

Takes a breakpoint name and creates a **max-width** media query that targets screen sizes up to *and including* the given breakpoint.

Because this is inclusive, the max-width will be the value of the next breakpoint up.

```js
// Styles will be applies to screen sizes from 0 up to and including "md"
[theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
  // styles
}
```

#### breakpoints.between(start, end)

Takes two breakpoint names, and creates a media query that targets screen sizes from the first breakpoint, up to *and including* the second breakpoint.

```js
// Styles will be applies to screen sizes from "sm" up to
// and including "lg"
[theme.breakpoints.between('sm', 'lg')]: {
  // styles
}
```

---

#### breakpoints.values

An object containing the breakpoint values defined in the theme

```js
{xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 960, lg: 1280, xl: 1920}
```

#### breakpoints.width(breakpoint)

This function is used to get the value of a specific breakpoint.

```js
theme.breakpoints.width('sm')  // => 600
```

Comment: Thanks Luke! But why it is (600 + theme.spacing.unit*4) and not just (600)? This code snippet is taken from material ui source code.

Comment: Do you know what file it was in?

Comment: Material-UI uses an [8 point grid](https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#baseline) for layout & spacing...

Comment: `theme.spacing.unit` (8) is the base unit for the layout grid.  So all  of the margins/padding  etc are multiples of `theme.spacing.unit`.  That code snippet is a media query for 600px plus 16px * 2, which is probably to account for left/right margin/padding.

Comment: Thanks Luke! I understood the concept. This actually means that if the screen size is below the mentioned value for breakpoints.up, none of the specified padding and margin will be applicable.

Comment: Exactly. It sets the width to 600px as long as screen size is at least 600px + 16px * 2, which leaves at least 16px of space on either side.

Comment: `theme.breakpoints.down('sm')` translates to `@media (max-width: 959.95px)`. That seems weird to me (material-ui 4.2.1)

Comment: Hmm... this answer was written for Material UI v1.x, so it might need to be updated. I

Comment: @LukePeavey how can we know that this is the current breakdown of theme in react? Which breakdown was applied on rendered component? How can we set a drawer by using a current breakdown condition? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: For me `theme.breakpoints.values.sm` worked instead of: `theme.breakpoints.width('sm')`