# Make responsive width passed throught props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I´m using material UI in React and I created a textField component to reuse it over all the app. The issue I´m facing is **when I try to make responsive these components I don´t know how to set up the breakpoints.**

Here you have an example:

```
<InputBaseComponent
   placeholder={"Nickname"}
   size={"small"}
   width={250}  --->how can I set up the breakpoints??
   type="text"
   name={"nickname"}
   id={"nickname"}
   onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: I´m using material UI breakpoints

Comment: Are you looking for something  like this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484812/reactjs-material-ui-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

You can create a customized component using material-UI withStyles HOC as

```
import { withStyles, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

export const MyTextField = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 350,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      width: '100%'
    },
    // more breakpoints can be added here also styles
  },
}))(TextField);
```

And it can be used as normal TextField

```
<MyTextField 
   placeholder={"Nickname"}
   size={"small"}
   type="text"
   name={"nickname"}
   id={"nickname"}
/>
```