# how to add media query in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, material-design

could you please tell me how to add media query in material UI ?
I checked this link

[ReactJS: Material ui breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484812/reactjs-material-ui-breakpoints)

it is mentioned that `down` function is used for `max-width` and `up` mean `min-width`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-meitner-iyu90?file=/src/App.js

```
 const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
  console.log(matches);
```

Material UI have following break points

```
xs (extra-small): 0px or larger
sm (small): 600px or larger
md (medium): 960px or larger
lg (large): 1280px or larger
xl (extra-large): 1920px or larger
```

it is not giving me expected output why ???

from this line `useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));` it should give `true` when width is less than `600px` but it giving me wrong output why ??

Currently it is giving me output `true` when width is less than `960` and `false` when it is greater than `960`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your app in ThemeProvider like so and replacing `down` with `up`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import App from "./App";

    const theme = createMuiTheme();

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      rootElement
    );
```

here a full working link [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sky-vqlvk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: please check answer

Comment: not working..it gives true when width is less than 960

Comment: now it working you need to replace `down` with `up` check the sandbox again.

Answer (score -1):

**using the styled component in react, you can add like,**

import styled from "styled-components";

```
export const OutterListWrapper = styled.div`
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 400px) {
top: -40px !important;
}
`;
```

Comment: i don't wan to use styled component

Comment: _then you can add a CSS file and use class or id_
`body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}`