# How can I move a column to a row when UI changes screen/size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my UI.

[image]

Now here is my UI after I adjust the size of the browser.

[image]

I want the left handside component to appear and then you scroll and see the second handside component.

I have one master component which is the called the problem form... it's where the left pane, the right pane, the buttons and the stepper component all come together.

I then render each component in there. I have one whole grid that hosts all of these compoenents. I.E. the left pane and right pane also are grids are have a size of 6 and 4.

Here is my Code.

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import ProgressionBar from "./ProblemProgressionBar/ProgressionBar";
import LeftPane from "./ProblemLeftPane/ProblemLeftPane";
import RightPane from "./ProblemRightPane/ProblemRightPane";
import ProblemStepperContext from "../Store/problem-stepper-context";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import ArrowCircleRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowCircleRight";
import ArrowCircleLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowCircleLeft";

const ProblemForm = () => {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

  const nextStep = () => {
    if (activeStep < 3) {
      setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevStep = () => {
    if (activeStep > 0) {
      setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ProblemStepperContext.Provider value={{ activeStep, setActiveStep }}>
      <Grid
        container
        item={true}
        alignItems="strech"
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        <ProgressionBar />
        <LeftPane />
        <RightPane />
        <Grid container xs={10} item={true}>
          <Grid container xs={6} item={true} justifyContent="flex-start" alignContent="flex-start">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="ArrowCircleLeftIcon"
              size="large"
              onClick={prevStep}
            >
              <ArrowCircleLeftIcon
                sx={{ fontSize: "50px" }}
                style={{ color: "#f0b67f" }}
              />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container xs={6} item={true} justifyContent="flex-end" alignContent="flex-end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="ArrowCircleRightIcon"
              size="large"
              onClick={nextStep}
            >
              <ArrowCircleRightIcon
                sx={{ fontSize: "50px" }}
                style={{ color: "#f0b67f" }}
              />
            </IconButton>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ProblemStepperContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProblemForm;
```

Here are my left pane and right pane components.

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Styles from "./RightPaneStyling.module.css";

const RightPane = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container xs={4} item={true} className={Styles.containerOutline} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
      <Grid xs={6} item={true} className={Styles.innerContainerOutLine}> 
        <h1 className={Styles.title}>Here is a good example</h1>
        <h1 className={Styles.problemTitle}>Two Sum</h1>
        <p className={Styles.problemDescription}>
          Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices
          of the two numbers such that they add up to target. You may assume
          that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use
          the same element twice. You can return the answer in any order.
        </p>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default RightPane;
```

```
import { Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import styles from "./ProblemLeftPaneStyles.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const ProblemLeftPaneV1 = (props) => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("problemDescription") === null
      ? ""
      : localStorage.getItem("problemDescription")
  );
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("problemTitle") === null
      ? ""
      : localStorage.getItem("problemTitle")
  );

  const updateDescription = (content) => {
    console.log(content);
    localStorage.setItem("problemDescription", content);
    setDescription(content);
  };

  const updateTitle = (event) => {
    localStorage.setItem("problemTitle", event.target.value);
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const log = () => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
    }
  };

  return (
    <Grid className={styles.leftPane} xs={6} item={true} container>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <form onSubmit={props.formSubmission}>
          <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
            <div id="titleSection">
              <h1 className={styles.title}>Name and describe your problem</h1>
              <h2 className={styles.subtitle}>
                It's great to provide examples, they allow the user to
                understand the problem
              </h2>
            </div>
            <li className={styles.marginBottom}>
              <label>Title</label>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                value={title}
                onChange={updateTitle}
              />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Description</label>
              <div>
                <Editor
                  onEditorChange={updateDescription}
                  onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
                  initialValue={description}
                  init={{
                    elementpath: false,
                    height: 500,
                    menubar: false,
                    plugins: [
                      "advlist",
                      "autolink",
                      "lists",
                      "link",
                      "image",
                      "charmap",
                      "anchor",
                      "searchreplace",
                      "visualblocks",
                      "code",
                      "fullscreen",
                      "insertdatetime",
                      "media",
                      "table",
                      "preview",
                      "wordcount",
                    ],
                    toolbar:
                      "undo redo | blocks | " +
                      "bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
                      "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
                      "removeformat",
                    content_style:
                      "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ProblemLeftPaneV1;
```

Comment: What you are requesting is to have a different display on different screens for that you need to make use CSS media queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: Material ui breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484812/reactjs-material-ui-breakpoints) Also see the [Breakpoints documentation]{https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You are using xs={4} means you want to use only 4 columns until screen meets xs size. I believe you can try doing it like xs={12} md={4}. By this you are using whole row that is all columns when screen size is between xs and md and before md you are using only 4 columns.

Try this

For Right Pane Starting line

```
<Grid container xs={12} md={4} item={true} className={Styles.containerOutline} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
```

For Left Pane

```
<Grid className={styles.leftPane} md={6} xs={12} item={true} container>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I have a better understanding of how the sizing of the Grids work now aswell, thank you very much.

Comment: Just a question off the back of that.. Do you know how to then center all the aligns in the Left Pane when it hit's the XS size